# Do our skin get normal after obese person lose weight?

Tags: dermatology, obesity, dermatochalasis-saggy, stretch-marks-striae

I have seen people loosing a lot of pounds working out. But their skin hanging all over the body. Does the skin get normal ever?

[image]

Comment: The medical term for this condition is, Panniculus. You can read about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panniculus. But to save your time it means, *"a dense layer of fatty tissue growth, consisting of subcutaneous fat in the lower abdominal area. It can be a result of obesity and can be mistaken for a tumor or hernia. Abdominal panniculus can be removed during abdominal panniculectomy, a type of abdominoplasty. **A panniculus can also be the result of loose tissues after pregnancy or massive weight loss."*** Hope knowing the term helps you with your research. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Hanging skin is typical when weight loss is sudden or too fast.

Skin is elastic, remember, so over time it'll shrink or expand as necessary but if you're losing weight too quickly, your skin won't have the time it needs to adapt.

When losing weight, you'll obviously be working to decrease your calorie intake to a deficit of what your body needs to maintain the weight but this has to be measured carefully if you're going to stay healthy when losing.

The recommended calorie deficit per day for healthy weight loss is 500 calories less than TDEE (total daily energy expenditure).

So if your TDEE calories is 1875 (the calories you need to consume to maintain your weight), then you'll want to aim for a maximum daily intake of 1375 calories. You can consider calories lost during exercise as "bonus calories."

#### Summary

Consuming too few calories per day when losing weight will mean you'll lose weight faster which could cause hanging skin.

Keep your calorie intake per day while losing weight to 500 calories less than you need to maintain your weight for healthy weight loss which will avoid the hanging skin problem.

Answer (score 0):

- [You Lost the Weight. What About That Extra Skin?](http://www.webmd.com/diet/obesity/features/you-lost-weight-what-about-extra-skin)
- [After Huge    Weight Loss, Sagging Skin Remains](http://www.nbcnews.com/health/health-news/after-huge-weight-loss-sagging-skin-remains-n44481)

Here are two good articles -- hopefully they answer some questions.

Best of luck going forward and congrats on the weight loss!

Comment: You're headed in the right direction but this is what we call a link-only answer. What happens to your answer when those links go dead? That's right, your answer becomes worthless. Please add text to your answer providing the important details. You can quote from the sources you cited.